How to efficiently mislead readers and catch them by surprise
I am working on a murder mystery and want to mislead my readers and create a false sense of security for them as to who the murderer is, but I have absolutely no idea how to start.

First of all, I recommend that you read a lot of murder mysteries with a writer's eye and analyze how they do this. You are not the first person writing that genre, so why reinvent the wheel.
Here are some techniques to mislead readers:

an unreliable narrator

the narrator lies
the narrator is mistaken


focus the narration on misleading clues ("red herring")
begin your narrative with a mistaken premise or false assumption
give your characters motivations that lead them astray in their search for the culprit or that make the suspects appear falsely guilty or innocent

There are also 29 other questions about misleading readers, you might want to take a look at some of them.

First and foremost, you are never going to fool everyone all the time, there are going to be people who see the end coming early, and not necessarily for any reason that can be easily discerned. My father worked out where The Village was going in the first act, I had a similar experience with Knives Out, and neither of us can watch either film and tell you what gave it away, if anything truly did.
To fool as many people as you can as often as you can consistency is key, if you have multiple POV characters they all need to be looking in the same direction so that the audience does too. Those characters should be looking in the same direction but for varied and individual reasons, and if one of them is the killer their reasons need, in hide-sight, to be about self-preservation and camouflage. If all your characters are looking at just one suspect in the same way, thinking them guilty for identical reasons, then seeing that character as a red herring is easy, even instinctual.
I would recommend Preston & Child's Special Agent Pendergast series as a good example of executing a narrative that keeps the reader in suspense and looking the wrong way without lying to them on some level. You get told everything the narrator knows, and a lot of what they suspect, while being in the dark with them about what is actually going down.

If you think you and your father figured out the ending of the works you mention, that is probably a very common cognitive error. There are many more movies and books where you didn't figure out the ending beforehand, but you only remember the one or two where accidentally your hunch (that was probably based more on similar stories than it was on anything in the book or movie itself) was proven correct. It's called "hindsight bias": https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hindsight_bias

If you have enough readers and all of them randomly guess the ending, there is a high likelihood that some of them will accidentally guess correct. And those will then strut around claiming, "I knew it all along!" So, to correct your answer: You can fool everyone! But some will guess the correct ending and then feel that they saw it coming, although they actually didn't.

@Ben No I've experienced that too and there's a marked difference between trying to to guess the ending, and just being disappointed when the story becomes blindingly obvious after a very short exposure to the material. It doesn't necessarily make the story less enjoyable but it can make the ending less satisfying.

In you answer you said that "neither of us can ... tell you what gave it away", but now in your comment you say it was "blindingly obvious". One of both statements must therefore be wrong.

@Ben I can't tell you why/how I knew that the old man committed suicide when he didn't have to from watching 7mins of the movie I can tell you that the rest of the story was then blindingly obvious.
